# Solution for PDE $f f_x = a f_t + b$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Does anyone know the solution to this PDE, with $f = f(x,t)$

$$f f_x = a f_t + b$$

the boundary conditions are: $f(0,t) = 0$, $f(L,t) = \text{const}_1$, $f(x,0) = \text{const}_2$

Comment: Can you show us your effort?maybe we can understand what is your problem for this

Comment: It is the inviscid Burgers equation (the Hopf equation)
$$
f_t = \frac{1}{a} \left(\frac{f^2}{2}\right)_x - \frac{b}{a}
$$
with source term

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$ff_x=af_t+b$

$af_t-ff_x=-b$

Hint:

Follow the method in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics#Example:

$\dfrac{dt}{ds}=a$ , letting $t(0)=0$ , we have $t=as$

$\dfrac{df}{ds}=-b$ , letting $f(0)=f_0$ , we have $f=f_0-bs=f_0-\dfrac{bt}{a}$

$\dfrac{dx}{ds}=-f=bs-f_0$ , letting $x(0)=g(f_0)$ , we have $x=\dfrac{bs^2}{2}-f_0s+g(f_0)=g\left(f+\dfrac{bt}{a}\right)-\dfrac{ft}{a}-\dfrac{bt^2}{2a^2}$

Comment: This method works till a shock is formed. Depending on the BC a shock may already be formed at $t =0$

Answer (score 1):

Let us solve $af_t - ff_x = -b$ over $0\leq x \leq L$, $t>0$ with the prescribed initial and boundary conditions.
In some cases, the solution can be deduced from the method of characteristics.
Here, there are three families of characteristic curves. We have the curves
\begin{aligned}
&x = \frac{b}{2a^2} (t - t_0)^2 &&\text{where}\quad f = -\frac{b}{a}(t-t_0), && t_0>0\\
&x = \frac{b}{2a^2} t^2 - \frac{c_2}{a}t + x_0 &&\text{where}\quad f = -\frac{b}{a}t + c_2, && 0\leq x_0\leq L\\
&x = \frac{b}{2a^2} (t - t_0)^2 - \frac{{c}_1}{a}(t - t_0) + L &&\text{where}\quad f = -\frac{b}{a}(t-t_0) + c_1, && t_0>0
\end{aligned}
under the requirements $a\neq 0$, $b>0$. The solutions deduced from these relations are valid provided that they are unique (i.e. characteristic curves carrying different informations do not intersect). In the present configuration, characteristics with different information almost always intersect somewhere. Therefore, the nature and expression of the solution (shock, rarefaction, etc.) will be highly dependent on the values of the parameters.